# Using CSS3Pie in Wordpress... Doing everything right, still not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, css3pie

I'm trying to get the corners rounded in IE8 on the navigation tabs of my slider: csr.steelcase.com ...("Our Vision", "Note from our CEO", etc)

The site is programmed in WordPress, and I've installed CSS3PIE correctly as per several articles I've read, but for whatever reason, I still can't get the corners to round in IE8. I've also tried linking to the PIE.htc file instead... no avail.

```
 body.company .flex-control-paging li a.flex-active{background: white; color:#333;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
zoom: 1;
position: relative;
behavior: url(http://csr.steelcase.com/wp-content/themes/steelcase360_theme_csr/pie_ver1/PIE.php);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIE.htc only supports the shorthand version of border radius, so use this:

```
body.company .flex-control-paging li a.flex-active{
    background: white;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url(http://csr.steelcase.com/wp-content/themes/steelcase360_theme_csr/pie_ver1/PIE.php);
}
```

http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius

Comment: Hey, no prob. Love PIE.htc and use it a lot. :)